# SQL Query generated by Visual Studio is really slow

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I'm using SSDT in order to compare database to my project database and query that runs timeouts. It's the following:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT 
        SCHEMA_NAME([o].[schema_id])    AS [SchemaName],
        [si].[object_id]                AS [ColumnSourceId],
        [o].[name]                      AS [ColumnSourceName],
        [o].[type]                      AS [ColumnSourceType],
        [ic].[column_id]                AS [ColumnId],
        [c].[name]                      AS [ColumnName],
        [si].[index_id]                 AS [IndexId],
        [si].[name]                     AS [IndexName],
        [ds].[type]                     AS [DataspaceType],
        [ds].[data_space_id]            AS [DataspaceId],
        [ds].[name]                     AS [DataspaceName],
        [si].[fill_factor]              AS [FillFactor],
        [si].[is_padded]                AS [IsPadded],
        [si].[is_disabled]              AS [IsDisabled],
        [si].[allow_page_locks]         AS [DoAllowPageLocks],
        [si].[allow_row_locks]          AS [DoAllowRowLocks],
        [sit].[cells_per_object]        AS [CellsPerObject],
        [sit].[bounding_box_xmin]       AS [XMin],
        [sit].[bounding_box_xmax]       AS [XMax],
        [sit].[bounding_box_ymin]       AS [YMin],
        [sit].[bounding_box_ymax]       AS [YMax],
        [sit].[level_1_grid]            AS [Level1Grid],
        [sit].[level_2_grid]            AS [Level2Grid],
        [sit].[level_3_grid]            AS [Level3Grid],
        [sit].[level_4_grid]            AS [Level4Grid],
        [sit].[tessellation_scheme]     AS [TessellationScheme],
        [s].[no_recompute]              AS [NoRecomputeStatistics],
        [p].[data_compression]          AS [DataCompressionId],
        CONVERT(bit, CASE WHEN [ti].[data_space_id] = [ds].[data_space_id] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                                        AS [EqualsParentDataSpace]
FROM
        [sys].[spatial_indexes]          AS [si] WITH (NOLOCK)
        INNER JOIN [sys].[objects]       AS [o] WITH (NOLOCK) ON [si].[object_id] = [o].[object_id]
        INNER JOIN [sys].[spatial_index_tessellations] [sit] WITH (NOLOCK) ON [si].[object_id] = [sit].[object_id] AND [si].[index_id] = [sit].[index_id]
        INNER JOIN [sys].[data_spaces]   AS [ds] WITH (NOLOCK) ON [ds].[data_space_id] = [si].[data_space_id] 
        INNER JOIN [sys].[index_columns] AS [ic] WITH (NOLOCK) ON [si].[object_id] = [ic].[object_id] AND [si].[index_id] = [ic].[index_id]
        INNER JOIN [sys].[columns]       AS [c] WITH (NOLOCK) ON [si].[object_id] = [c].[object_id] AND [ic].[column_id] = [c].[column_id]
        INNER JOIN [sys].[objects]       AS [o2] WITH (NOLOCK) ON [o2].[parent_object_id] = [si].[object_id]
        INNER JOIN [sys].[stats]         AS [s] WITH (NOLOCK) ON [o2].[object_id] = [s].[object_id] AND [s].[name] = [si].[name]
        INNER JOIN [sys].[partitions]    AS [p] WITH (NOLOCK) ON [p].[object_id] = [o2].[object_id] AND [p].[partition_number] = 1
        LEFT  JOIN [sys].[indexes]       AS [ti] WITH (NOLOCK) ON [o].[object_id] = [ti].[object_id]
        LEFT JOIN [sys].[tables]         AS [t] WITH (NOLOCK) ON [t].[object_id] = [si].[object_id]
WHERE [si].[is_hypothetical] = 0
        AND [ti].[index_id] < 2
        AND OBJECTPROPERTY([o].[object_id], N'IsSystemTable') = 0

        AND ([t].[is_filetable] = 0 OR [t].[is_filetable] IS NULL)
        AND ([o].[is_ms_shipped] = 0 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                        FROM [sys].[extended_properties]
                                        WHERE     [major_id] = [o].[object_id]
                                              AND [minor_id] = 0
                                              AND [class] = 1
                                              AND [name] = N'microsoft_database_tools_support'
                                       ))
) AS [_results];
```

That's the plan it generates: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1gm9wWDG

Performance penalty comes from clause

```
AND OBJECTPROPERTY([o].[object_id], N'IsSystemTable') = 0
```

Running statistics update resolves the issue, however it's a hack and a temporal solution:

```
UPDATE STATISTICS sys.sysidxstats;
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Another user experiencing this issue has a question (with a solution) in DBA StackExchange - I think this should help. See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/163703/sqlpackage-exe-select-statement-causing-massive-reads

Comment: Thanks @Kevin! I'll check it out.